# Mailjet Api Using C#

Tags: c#, mailjet

i am using c# language for accessing MailJet Api,not sure what are the parameters required as has given for cURl 
i am newbie , how do i get started with it , please let me know any answer would be helpful

Comment: There's [an official API library](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-dotnet) ([Mailjet.Api on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mailjet.Api/)) if you don't want to make the REST calls yourself. Or are you asking for help using that?

Answer (score 2):

Install the nuget package: Mailjet.Api

Review the documentation at: https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-dotnet

There are examples of code on there.

Here's an example piece of code from Github where a client is created and resource created.

```
MailjetClient client = new MailjetClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiSecret"]);

            MailjetRequest request = new MailjetRequest()
            {
                Resource = Contact.Resource,
            }
            .Property(Contact.Email, "Mister@mailjet.com");

            MailjetResponse response = await client.PostAsync(request);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("StatusCode: {0}\n", response.StatusCode));

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total: {0}, Count: {1}\n", response.GetTotal(), response.GetCount()));
                Console.WriteLine(response.GetData());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ErrorInfo: {0}\n", response.GetErrorInfo()));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ErrorMessage: {0}\n", response.GetErrorMessage()));
            }
```

Comment: Getting this result : "Id = 76, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}" , what could be the problem ?

Comment: @PradipKondalkar check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129427/api-request-waitingforactivation-not-yet-computed-error

Comment: Also @PradipKondalkar if my answer has helped please mark it as Accepted.