# Group not created via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I might be missing some steps as to why the group is not being created.

1. Followed C# from the second sample
2. Used Client Credentials authorization provider
3. Setup API Permissions in the Github Enterprise Cloud application (in App Registrations) for Group and Directory
4. Granted consent.
5. No errors encountered, just Waiting result but checked in the Azure portal, group has not been created.

Comment: Are you following this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-create-a-group-with-owners-and-members) and are you facing any error? What permissions have you consented for group creation?

Comment: Yes any of those examples. All checked (delegated and application) for Directory, Group, Domain, User, Member, TeamMember, GroupMember. @Shiva-MSFTIdentity

Comment: Out of touch coding, I resolved by stumbling upon this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129427/api-request-waitingforactivation-not-yet-computed-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of touch coding, I resolved by stumbling upon this question.

[API request WaitingForActivation "Not yet computed" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129427/api-request-waitingforactivation-not-yet-computed-error)

The error is now defined when running unit test.